# Multi column text editor in the terminal?

Tags: command-line, editor

I use the terminal for most work and make a lot of lists, work with song lyrics etc. I do a lot of vertical scrolling while two thirds of the screen to the right are blank.

So is it possible to have columns in any terminal app?
(Below - scrolling required in terminal to review all items)
[image: Document in terminal requires vertical scrolling]

(Below - no scrolling required in LibreOffice to columns)
[image: Doc in LO requires no scrolling thanks to columns]

Comment: You can do something similar in vim, but (as with most things in vim) there's somewhat of a learning curve to it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5131205/how-to-edit-text-in-multiple-columns-in-vim#5131298 Basically, you open the same file in multiple splits and "lock" the scrolling positions of the splits to each other.

Comment: Can you show a sample of what you're editing and how you're planning to edit it?

Comment: I've updated with some images showing how more content is visible on LibreOffice with columns than in a plain editor in the terminal (nano here). @HenningKockerbeck - thank you. That's at least one option. But as a Dvorak typist - VIM isn't the easiest.

Answer (score 1):

Open the file in emacs, type `C-x 3` as many times to create your columns, then `M-x follow-mode`

https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Follow-Mode.html

I also spend most of my time in terminal, but usually through emacs. It's a sort of desktop environment for the command line.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested you could go the vim route or you could get a similar result by using a [terminal multiplexer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_multiplexer) such as [tmux](https://tmux.github.io/) to have multiple shell sessions, each running a separate text editor inside a unique terminal session.

*I don't know if this suits your needs but I figured having an alternative to learning vim is always a nice thing :3*

Comment: I'll try this (and come back here and comment). Thanks :)

Comment: I'm using byobu and can't get it to do this for me. It warns against nesting sessions. I can have use two separate terminal windows to make it happen but that's not what I'm looking for.